# Changing the properties of the <object> tag ONLY, which contains an SVG element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I am working on an object element that contains an SVG image in it. I am aware that inorder to select the SVG inside it I have to do this:

```
var svgObject = $('#SVG_Object')[0].contentDocument ; //Traverse in to the document

/*Now to select the item inside the SVG document*/
$('#SVG_Item',svgObject).css({'fill':'lime'}) ;//select the item and change its color
```

We all know that, we cannot select the SVG directly, we have to go through the above mentioned steps inorder to do some changes to the SVG. Now, heres the question, Is there way to select **ONLY** the Object tag as a whole and do changes to the object tag as a Whole ? The problem is specifically about positioning. I have this scenario going on:

```
<!--HTML--> <object data="img/image.svg" id="SVGObject"><object>

/*CSS*/ #SVGObject{position: relative; left: 123px ; top: 123px ;}

/*Javascript*/ $('#SVGbject').animate({'left':523},600,'linear');
```

You see from the above code, I want to animate **ONLY** the positioning of object tag instead of animating the SVG itself. Ofcourse, the code does not work, however, **Is there way to do it ?**
I would really appreciate your responses. Please forgive me if the description is not enough do let me know if you require any further information regarding this scenario. Thanks for your HElP !!

Comment: I might be mistaken, but if you're animating a position, don't you need to add `px` to the end of it? or at the very least, add `+=` to the beginning of it? `{'left':'523px'}`, or `{'left':'+=523'}`

Comment: Probably the easiest thing to do is just wrap the `<object>` in a `<div>` and animate that instead.

Comment: @ntgCleaner No, jQuery defaults to `px` if units aren't specified so `523` = `523px`

Comment: @Rhumborl  Thanks a lot it works that way, however, I had this question that How come we can style an object but cannot do any changes to it using Javscript ? Could you link me to some resources  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery code has an error ... otherwise, it's correct; you **can animate the object** ...

Change ...

```
$('#SVGbject').animate({'left':523},600,'linear');
```

... to ...

```
$('#SVGObject').animate({'left':523},600,'linear');
```

With the correct reference, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/uopzupn7/

Added a Plunk for better handling of external SVG file per documentation below.

http://plnkr.co/edit/tQiscH?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for notifying about the mistake. well true it works however my question is in regards to an SVG inside the object tag and not an empty object tag.

Comment: Your question was that you want to animate "animate ONLY the positioning of object tag instead of animating the SVG itself" ... this animates the object tag; granted in my example, there is no SVG.  Were you looking to animate the object tag WITHOUT moving the SVG?  That's a different question.

Comment: I updated by fiddle to match yours, but I'm still not sure what the question is, so it's hard to work toward a correct answer.

Comment: the thing is the Svg is inserted as <object data="img/example.svg"></object>, keeping anything in between the object tags has a different purpose. Hence I asked the object as a whole which is including the SVG but not affecting the SVG inside the object tag. @rfornal

Comment: A plunk has been added (http://plnkr.co/edit/tQiscH?p=preview) the SVG is not modified and moves with the object.  Did I miss something?

Comment: thanks for your answer, to be honest I really do not understand why   its not working for me, what phenomenon is this. I have tested it individually in a fiddle, it works however in the project that i am working on, the animate() has no effect on the object, I dont understand whats going on, do you have any thoughts about this ?

Comment: Generally, with something like that, I would suspect you have created multiple objects using the `#SVGObject` id ... and the animate would ONLY work on the first one; if it is hidden, there's nothing to see.  Make the id and the reference to it MORE unique (say, `SVGObject_id001` or something like that) in the HTML and when using the `.animate` code ...